# How to solve "does not have a NavController set"

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment

I want to reach Detail Fragment from Main Fragment.

> ERROR
> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.cardview.widget.CardView{7fe29a5 VFE...C.. ...P.... 0,0-381,319 #7f080085 app:id/container} does not have a NavController set
> W/System.err:     at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.kt:71)
> W/System.err:     at com.isilon.beinconnect.ui.main.adapter.MainAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-0(MainAdapter.kt:68)
> W/System.err:     at com.isilon.beinconnect.ui.main.adapter.MainAdapter.$r8$lambda$J_WJtHWaCOLmqLIL361QlbA-I6M(Unknown Source:0)
> W/System.err:     at com.isilon.beinconnect.ui.main.adapter.MainAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:6)
> Adapter

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position:   Int) {
              holder.bind(data[position])
    
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
    
                val resultData = data[position]
    
    
                val action =          MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment()
                action.releaseDate = resultData.release_date
                val navController = Navigation.findNavController(holder.itemView)
                navController.navigate(action)
            }
        }
```

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> DETAIL XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".ui.main.view.DetailFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_detail_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_adult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_release_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> NAVIGATION

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.isilon.beinconnect.ui.main.view.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_detailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.isilon.beinconnect.ui.main.view.DetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" >
        <argument
            android:name="releaseDate"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="No Release Date" />
        <argument
            android:name="avatar"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="No Avatar Img" />
        <argument
            android:name="adult"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

findNavController won't work for views added programmatically and not attached to parent view like viweholders
so you need to find nav controller for recyclerview instead of viewholder itmeview

```
private var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView? = null
override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView
}

override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    mRecyclerView = null// to avoid memory leak
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position:   Int) {
    holder.bind(data[position])
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
        val resultData = data[position]
        val action =          MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment()
        action.releaseDate = resultData.release_date
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(mRecyclerView!!)
        navController.navigate(action)
    }
}
```

Q: why findNavController won't work for views added programmatically?
A: Because nav controller add tags to all views when created with weak reference to itself, so when you add view programmatically and not attached to parent, findNavController won't be able to get your root view and thus won't be able to find its weak reference.

Comment: Thanks @Islam but I have got same issue

Comment: Are you able to push your code to github and we can look into it

Comment: I added more code blocks from my project.
I will be glad if you review

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like that

```
(itemView.context as AppCompatActivity).findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView).navigate(action)
```

Comment: I can see the data I sent to the detail page in the log, but the detail page does not open.